# Python mock multiple queries in a function using pytest_mock

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest, psycopg2

I am writing unit test case for a function which has multiple sql queries in it.I am using `psycopg2` module and trying to mock the `cursor`.

**app.py**

```py
import psycopg2

def my_function():
    # all connection related code goes here ...

    query = "SELECT name,phone FROM customer WHERE name='shanky'"
    cursor.execute(query)
    columns = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]
    customer_response = []
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        customer_response.append(dict(zip(columns, row)))

    query = "SELECT name,id FROM product WHERE name='soap'"
    cursor.execute(query)
    columns = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]
    product_response = []
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        product_response.append(dict(zip(columns, row)))

    return product_response
```

**test.py**

```py
from pytest_mock import mocker
import psycopg2

def test_my_function(mocker):
    from my_module import app
    mocker.patch('psycopg2.connect')

    #first query
    mocked_cursor_one = psycopg2.connect.return_value.cursor.return_value
    mocked_cursor_one.description = [['name'],['phone']]
    mocked_cursor_one.fetchall.return_value = [('shanky', '347539593')]
    mocked_cursor_one.execute.call_args == "SELECT name,phone FROM customer WHERE name='shanky'"

    #second query
    mocked_cursor_two = psycopg2.connect.return_value.cursor.return_value
    mocked_cursor_two.description = [['name'],['id']]
    mocked_cursor_two.fetchall.return_value = [('nirma', 12313)]
    mocked_cursor_two.execute.call_args == "SELECT name,id FROM product WHERE name='soap'"

    ret = app.my_function()
    assert ret == {'name' : 'nirma', 'id' : 12313}
```

But the mocker always takes the last mock object (the second query).I have already tried multiple hacks, but that didn't work out. How can i mock multiple queries in one function and successfully pass the unit test case? Is it possible to write a unit test case in this fashion or do i need to split the queries in different functions?

Comment: Have you heard about @pytest.mark.parametrize? In my own humble opinion, unit test functions should always test only one use case. That being said, parametrize lets you pass different arguments to the same function and runs it in a loop. So it would be executed 2 times. On the other hand, I have mocked databases before and it's sometimes really useful to create a full-mock, meaning re-coding the behavior of the module. But this also means you need to create functions to parse sql querie, I usually get the data from a json. It's harder, but cleaner and soo much more portable.

Comment: Hey @MaxSirwa , thanks for your input. I tried getting an understanding about what you mentioned, it would help me a lot if you can post an example for this use case.Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After drilling a lot through the documentation, I was able to achieve this with the help of `unittest` mock decorator and `side_effect` which was suggested by @Pavel Vergeev.I was able to write a unit test case that is good enough to test the functionality.

```py
from unittest import mock
from my_module import app

@mock.patch('psycopg2.connect')
def test_my_function(mocked_db):

    mocked_cursor = mocked_db.return_value.cursor.return_value

    description_mock = mock.PropertyMock()
    type(mocked_cursor).description = description_mock

    fetchall_return_one = [('shanky', '347539593')]

    fetchall_return_two = [('nirma', 12313)]

    descriptions = [
        [['name'],['phone']],
        [['name'],['id']]
    ]

    mocked_cursor.fetchall.side_effect = [fetchall_return_one, fetchall_return_two]

    description_mock.side_effect = descriptions

    ret = app.my_function()

    # assert whether called with mocked side effect objects
    mocked_db.assert_has_calls(mocked_cursor.fetchall.side_effect)

    # assert db query count is 2
    assert mocked_db.return_value.cursor.return_value.execute.call_count == 2

    # first query
    query1 = """
            SELECT name,phone FROM customer WHERE name='shanky'
            """
    assert mocked_db.return_value.cursor.return_value.execute.call_args_list[0][0][0] == query1

    # second query
    query2 = """
            SELECT name,id FROM product WHERE name='soap'
            """
    assert mocked_db.return_value.cursor.return_value.execute.call_args_list[1][0][0] == query2

    # assert the data of response
    assert ret == {'name' : 'nirma', 'id' : 12313}
```

In addition to this if there are dynamic parameters in the query, that can be asserted too by the following method.

```py
assert mocked_db.return_value.cursor.return_value.execute.call_args_list[0][0][1] = (parameter_name,)
```

so when the first query is executed, `cursor.execute(query,(parameter_name,))` at `call_args_list[0][0][0]` the query can be obtained and asserted, at `call_args_list[0][0][1]` the first parameter `parameter_name` can be obtained. similarly incrementing the index, all the other params and different queries can be obtained and asserted.

Answer (score 2):

Try `side_effect` argument of `mocker.patch`:

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock
from pytest_mock import mocker
import psycopg2

def test_my_function(mocker):
    from my_module import app
    mocker.patch('psycopg2.connect', side_effect=[MagicMock(), MagicMock()])

    #first query
    mocked_cursor_one = psycopg2.connect().cursor.return_value  # note that we actually call psyocpg2.connect -- it's important
    mocked_cursor_one.description = [['name'],['phone']]
    mocked_cursor_one.fetchall.return_value = [('shanky', '347539593')]
    mocked_cursor_one.execute.call_args == "SELECT name,phone FROM customer WHERE name='shanky'"

    #second query
    mocked_cursor_two = psycopg2.connect().cursor.return_value
    mocked_cursor_two.description = [['name'],['id']]
    mocked_cursor_two.fetchall.return_value = [('nirma', 12313)]
    mocked_cursor_two.execute.call_args == "SELECT name,id FROM product WHERE name='soap'"

    assert mocked_cursor_one is not mocked_cursor_two  # show that they are different

    ret = app.my_function()
    assert ret == {'name' : 'nirma', 'id' : 12313}
```

As per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect), `side_effect` allows you to change returned value each time the patched object is called:

> If you pass in an iterable, it is used to retrieve an iterator which must yield a value on every call. This value can either be an exception instance to be raised, or a value to be returned from the call to the mock

Comment: are you missing any imports in the code? and it would be great if you could explain what `side_effect` actually does

Comment: @RajanSharma thank you, I fixed the imports and added additional explanation.

Comment: I am not able to get the mocked response in the function when i print it. I am getting an empty array for `columns` and `customer_response`.

Comment: also i am getting `StopIteration` when i run your code

Answer (score 2):

As I have mentioned in an earlier comment, the best way to make unit testing portable is to develop a complete Mock of your database's behavior.
I've done it for MySQL but it's pretty much the same for all databases.

First of all, I like using wrapper classes over the packages I'm using, it helps quickly change the database at one place instead of changing it everywhere in the code.

Here's a samople of what I use as a wrapper:

Now, you would need to Mock this MySQL class:

```
# _database.py
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Database Metaclass
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
"""Metaclass for Database implementation.
"""
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------


import logging


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class Database:
    """Database Metaclass"""

    def __init__(self, connect_func, **kwargs):
        self.connection = connect_func(**kwargs)

    def execute(self, statement, fetchall=True):
        """Execute a statement.

        Execute the statement passed as arugment.

        Args:
            statement (str): SQL Query or Command to execute.

        Returns:
            set: List of returned objects by the cursor.
        """
        cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        logger.debug(f"Executing: {statement}")
        cursor.execute(statement)
        if fetchall:
            return cursor.fetchall()
        else:
            return cursor.fetchone()

    def __del__(self):
        """Close connection on object deletion."""
        self.connection.close()
```

And the mysql module:

```
# mysql.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# MySQL Database Class
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
"""Class for MySQL Database connection."""
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------


import logging
import mysql.connector

from . import _database


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class MySQL(_database.Database):
    """Snowflake Database Class Wrapper.

    Attributes:
        connection (obj): Object returned from mysql.connector.connect
    """

    def __init__(self, autocommit=True, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(connect_func=mysql.connector.connect, **kwargs)
        self.connection.autocommit = autocommit
```

Instantiate like: `db = MySQL(user='...', password='...', ...)`

Here's the data file:

```
# database_mock_data.json
{
    "customer": {
        "name": [
            "shanky",
            "nirma"
        ],
        "phone": [
            123123123,
            232342342
        ]
    },
    "product": {
        "name": [
            "shanky",
            "nirma"
        ],
        "id": [
            1,
            2
        ]
    }
}
```

The mocks.py

```
# mocks.py
import json
import re
from . import mysql
_MOCK_DATA_PATH = 'database_mock_data.json'


class MockDatabase(MySQL):
    """
    """
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.connection = MockConnection()


class MockConnection:
    """
    Mock the connection object by returning a mock cursor.
    """
    @staticmethod
    def cursor():
        return MockCursor()


class MockCursor:
    """
    The Mocked Cursor

    A call to execute() will initiate the read on the json data file and will set
    the description object (containing the column names usually).

    You could implement an update function like `_json_sql_update()`
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.description = []
        self.__result = None

    def execute(self, statement):
        data = _read_json_file(_MOCK_DATA_PATH)
        if statement.upper().startswith('SELECT'):
            self.__result, self.description = _json_sql_select(data, statement)

    def fetchall(self):
        return self.__result

    def fetchone(self):
        return self.__result[0]


def _json_sql_select(data, query):
    """
    Takes a dictionary and returns the values from a sql query.
    NOTE: It does not work with other where clauses than '='.
          Also, note that a where statement is expected.
    :param (dict) data: Dictionary with the following structure:
                        {
                            'tablename': {
                                'column_name_1': ['value1', 'value2],
                                'column_name_2': ['value1', 'value2],
                                ...
                            },
                            ...
                        }
    :param (str) query: An update sql query as:
                        `update TABLENAME set column_name_1='value'
                        where column_name_2='value1'`
    :return: List of list of values and header description
    """
    try:
        match = (re.search("select(.*)from(.*)where(.*)[;]?", query,
                 re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL).groups())
    except AttributeError:
        print("Select Query pattern mismatch... {}".format(query))
        raise

    # Parse values from the select query
    tablename = match[1].strip().upper()

    columns = [col.strip().upper() for col in match[0].split(",")]
    if columns == ['*']:
        columns = data[tablename].keys()

    where = [cmd.upper().strip().replace(' ', '')
             for cmd in match[2].split('and')]

    # Select values
    selected_values = []
    nb_lines = len(list(data[tablename].values())[0])
    for i in range(nb_lines):
        is_match = True
        for condition in where:
            key_condition, value_condition = (_clean_string(condition)
                                              .split('='))
            if data[tablename][key_condition][i].upper() != value_condition:
                # Set flag to yes
                is_match = False
        if is_match:
            sub_list = []
            for column in columns:
                sub_list.append(data[tablename][column][i])
            selected_values.append(sub_list)

    # Usual descriptor has nested list
    description = zip(columns, ['...'] * len(columns))

    return selected_values, description


def _read_json_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f_in:
        data = json.load(f_in)
    return data
```

And then you have your test in a test_module_yourfunction.py

```
import pytest

def my_function(db, query):
    # Code goes here

@pytest.fixture
def db_connection():
    return MockDatabase()


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    ("query", "expected"),
    [
        ("SELECT name,phone FROM customer WHERE name='shanky'", {'name' : 'nirma', 'id' : 12313}),
        ("<second query goes here>", "<second result goes here>")
    ]
)
def test_my_function(db_connection, query, expected):
    assert my_function(db_connection, query) == expected
```

Now I'm sorry if you can't copy/paste this code and make it work, but you get the feeling :) just trying to help

Comment: I get your idea, but it is not helping the cause. How do i let my program know that if it encounters some SQl query in the function for which i am writing unit test case, it needs to return some response and then going through the whole business logic, it returns some response that can be asserted.

Comment: Sorry man, was in a rush, I have actually made a mistake, the test_my_function should call your function. Let me fix that. Although it's not good practice to initiate your db connection inside your function, assuming it's passed as an argument (see updated code)

Comment: Also your function does not seem to return customer_response, so not sure what's the purpose, it'd be better if your function processes one query at a time, thus passing query as an argument might be a good solution.